# I can't enter 'ş' , 'ı' and 'ğ' in TextField

Tags: flutter

I can't enter 'ş' , 'ı' and 'ğ' in TextField. Even the onChanged event doesn't work when I want to enter these letters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an emulator-related issue.
My fault, it's not a TextField issue.
I can't delete the question as it has been answered.
So ignore this question.

Answer (score 0):

Add this property to your TextField

```html
keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
```

Comment: I already added :(